# Getting URL Value Out of an Input Field PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, youtube

What I am trying to achieve is similar to Facebook's post field.

When the user input contains a URL, fire a function called get embed that checks the entire input for a URL and then goes out to the respective oembed endpoint.

This works fine if the input is JUST a URL, however if its a URL with comments, then it doesn't work.

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsfdW5z9iSg`  This will work

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsfdW5z9iSg This is awesome` This will not work.

```
public function parse_url($message) {

    if (strpos($message, 'youtube.com') !== false) {
       $filter = filter_sanitize_url($message);
        $format = "&format=json";
        $val = urlencode($filter);
        $ep = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=";
        $full = $ep . $val . $format;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $full);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $decodedOutput = json_decode($output, true);
        return $decodedOutput;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest you post you current code

Comment: Added code to the post. Completely forgot lol!